In middleware.js, after setting logged in cookie, on Next 13.5 redirection the cookie not appearing in the browser
Here is my Next js middleware code, I am decrypting a JWE and then decoding the returned JWT and setting the payload in cookie named "session_id", and after that deleting the token from query param of the url and redirecting to the url without token. First time, it sets the cookie but after redirection the cookie does not appear in the browser, while I need it to maintain the session for the logged in user.
 if (
        !req.nextUrl.pathname.includes('/api') &&
        !req.nextUrl.pathname.includes('/route') &&
        !req.nextUrl.pathname.includes('/_next') &&
        !req.nextUrl.pathname.includes('/static') &&
        !req.nextUrl.pathname.includes('/ecruise_img') &&
        !req.nextUrl.pathname.includes('/manifest') &&
        req.nextUrl.pathname !== '/favicon.ico'
      ) {
        const token = searchParams.get('token');
        const alg = 'RSA-OAEP';
        const privateKey = await jose.importPKCS8(privateKeyPem, alg);
        const trimmedToken = token?.trim();
        const hasSessionCookie = cookies['session_id'];
        if (token) {
          if (hasSessionCookie == undefined) {
            try {
              const { plaintext } = await jose.compactDecrypt(
                trimmedToken,
                privateKey
              );
              const decodedPlaintext = new TextDecoder().decode(plaintext);
              const decodedJwt = jose.decodeJwt(decodedPlaintext);
              const serializedSessionCookie = cookie.serialize(
                'session_id',
                JSON?.stringify(decodedJwt),
                {
                  httpOnly: true,
                  // secure: true,
                  sameSite: 'strict',
                  path: '/',
                  domain: 'localhost',
                  maxAge: decodedJwt?.exp
                }
              );
              response.headers.append('Set-Cookie', serializedSessionCookie);
              if (
                response.headers
                  .get('Set-Cookie')
                  ?.includes(serializedSessionCookie)
              ) {
                nextUrl.searchParams.delete('token');
                // Redirect to the same URL but without the token parameter
                return NextResponse.redirect(nextUrl.href, 307);
              }
              return NextResponse.next();
            } catch (err) {
              console.error('Token decryption failed:', err);
              return redirectToLogin();
            }
          }
        } else if (!token && !hasSessionCookie) {
          console.log('No token and no session found, redirecting...');
          return redirectToLogin();
        }
      }

